# Reading in a data file and assigning each column to individual arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner to c++ and I am having a problem importing columns from a data file to individual arrays.
My data file looks something like this:

```
1 81 0 79 89 
2 81 0 79 89 
3 81 0 79 89 
4 81 0 79 89 
5 81 0 79 89 
6 81 0 79 89 
7 81 0 79 89 
8 81 0 79 89 
9 81 0 79 89 
10 81 0 79 89
```

Now what I want to do is import the first three columns into individual arrays. For example the array "happinessseries1" (which is associated with the 2nd column) should have values {81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81}.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

 ifstream inFile; 

 int neglible[100];         //size of arrays bigger than number of entries in data file
 int happinessseries1[100];
 int happinessseries2[100];

 int i=0;
inFile.open("happiness.dat");
if (inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 1;
}
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile >> neglible[i];
    inFile >> happinessseries1[i];
    inFile >> happinessseries2[i];
    i++;

    cout << happinessseries1[i] << endl;  // display values in the array to check that the correct values have been imported                                             
}
inFile.close();

return 0;

 }
```

The values that are displayed for happinessseries1 are not the same as the original column values. 
Can anyone see what is wrong in my code and how to correct it.
Also this is the first time I have posted a question so please let me know if I need to clarify anything.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Stop now and search StackOverflow for "C++ read file array".  There's already been questions asked this week about reading into arrays.

Comment: I believe, this is still a valid question, because OP has a problem with a specific piece of code. Just pointing him to where he can copy/paste the code that does what he wants doesn't answer his question. If his question was "How do I read values from a file into an array" I'd agree with you, but he's asking what's wrong with his solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that will take too long to address with your code, so in the meantime here's a naive example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int COLUMNS = 5;

    vector< vector <int> > data;

    string filename = "myfile.txt";

    ifstream ifile(filename.c_str());


    if (ifile.is_open()) {
        int num;

        vector <int> numbers_in_line;

        while (ifile >> num) {
            numbers_in_line.push_back(num);

            if (numbers_in_line.size() == COLUMNS) {
                data.push_back(numbers_in_line);
                numbers_in_line.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cerr << "There was an error opening the input file!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //now get the column from the 2d vector:
    vector <int> column;
    int col = 2;//example: the 2nd column

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        column.push_back(data[i][col - 1]);
        cout << column[i] << endl;
    }

    ifile.close();
}
```

This outputs:

```
81
81
81
81
81
81
81
81
81
81
```

As expected.

**Warning: there are no asserts to verify that the column you want is less than the number of columns read, or is there use of iterators. All of these you can do on your own.**

Regarding your code:

1. Your arrays are just that: arrays. This means that your program could (depending on the input supplied), either be appropriate, wasteful if there is too little data, or will crash if too much data is supplied. Use vectors instead as they are not only closely performant to regular arrays, but syntactically similar, and have extra functionality built-in to boot: such as they can be resized.
2. So, how to approach your problem? As others have mentioned previously, your data has 5 columns, so you can use that to your advantage. One way (as implemented above), is that after we've read five numbers we know that this constitutes a line, and we can read the next one. As such, this generic algorithm can be repeated for the remainder of the file, and will work for any given non-zero number of lines of input (of this format).
3. Lastly, once you've populated your data container, you can now iterate over it and extract the column(s) that you need as shown. For simplicity purposes, I've done so after I've read and populated the `data` vector, but this could have feasibly been done while reading as well (which is arguably faster).

Comment: Thank you this has helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap these two lines:

```
i++;
cout << happinessseries1[i] << endl;  // display values in the array to check that the correct values have been imported
```

You are incrementing `i`, and then printing out the value of the i'th element -- which hasn't been set yet! You should print, then increment.

Comment: Not the only problem, but good catch. +1 for that.  Edited my answer to mention this issue, too.

Comment: This has worked in the sense that it displays values that are at least present in the data file, however the array "happinesssseries1" gives me values from the rows of the file instead of the columns which is what I am looking for. Cheers for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You have more than three columns of data, you have five.  Right now you are just reading the file a number at a time as if there were only three columns of data.  If you KNOW you'll always have five columns, you could just cin into a throwaway variable twice to ignore the last two columns.  A "better" solution would be looking into stringstreams and cin.getline().

And make sure you aren't printing out uninitialized values.  Right now your are incrementing i and then printing out the array value.  Oops!

Answer (score 0):

Your example data has 5 numbers per line.

Your code seems to assume 3 number per line.

---

Also, you're outputting array items that have not yet been set, so that in addition to the data in the program being incorrect, the output has no relation to the data.

---

By the way, don't test for `!stream.eof()`, instead test `!stream.fail()`. Which can be written as just `stream`. And do check for failure after each read.

---

Also, by the way, don't return `1` from `main` to indicate failure. Even though it works on Windows and *nix platforms, it's platform specific. Instead use standard `EXIT_FAILURE`, from the `<stdlib.h>` header.

---

Also, by the way, consider using a tool such as AStyle to fix the indentantion.

It's impolite to leave the burden of fixing the idnentation, to SO readers.

---

And… do consider using **`std::vector`** instead of raw arrays.

Then you won't have a problem with e.g. file dataset size exceeding the array size.

Comment: All of these points that you have made have helped a great deal and sorry about the indentations, I am pretty new to SO and I am still getting my head around the etiquette :)